# NativeScript Pull to Refresh page behind ActionBar after refresh | nativescript-pulltorefresh

Tags: angular, plugins, nativescript

I'm using the `nativescript-pulltorefresh` plugin in a nativescript angular app.  As you see in the screenshots, the page displays property.  When a refresh is completed from the scrollview pull the view is shifted up behind the actionbar.  There is even a gap at the bottom of the page where the original content was.

Here is the page markup.  As some others have suggested in related posts, I have tried wrapping the `PullToRefresh` and `ScrollView` in an `AbsoluteLayout` and `GridLayout`.  The result was the same.

```
...
</ActionBar>

<PullToRefresh (refresh)="refreshList($event)" style="background- color: #F5F7FA;">
  <ScrollView>
    <GridLayout rows="auto, *" width="100%">
    ...
    </GridLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</PullToRefresh>
```

I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks!

[image: Before Pull Refresh]

[image: After Pull Refresh]

[image: Bottom of ScrollView showing gap]

Answer (score 2):

As luck would have it, reviewing the screenshots in my question gave me a clue to the problem.  The refresh was causing initial view in the ScrollView to resize.  By adding iosOverflowSafeArea="false" to the tag, it prevented this from happing and the view is performing as expected.

Comment: Thank you.  Solved my problem too.  And for anyone else this is where you add the iosOverflowSafeArea:  ` <ScrollView iosOverflowSafeArea="false">`